# Dynamically access master pages properties

Tags: asp.net

We can change masterpagefile for particular page dynamically.but how can i access their properies which are changing as per the master pages.

what code will give me their properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can add a public property to the code behind of your master page, like so:

```
public string MyMasterPageProperty {
 return "my stuff";
}
```

Then, on the content page, you can use this code to access your new property.

```
Page.Master.MyMasterPageProperty;
```

If you don't want to add the MasterType directive on the aspx page, you can always explicitly cast the Page.Master to the type of your master page, so that it looks like this:

```
((MyMasterPageClass)Page.Master).MyMasterPageProperty;
```

You can read more info here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210513005959/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/013107-1.aspx

Comment: How to access dynamically changed master pages properties in code

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the MasterType directive on the aspx page:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site1.Master" %>
```

Then on your aspx.cs page, you can call the properties of the master:

```
Master.Property1 = "whatever you wanna do";
```

If you need more instructions:

http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/back-basics-%E2%80%93-using-mastertype